# After a background color change with Javascript the :hover don't change the color

Tags: javascript, css

I have a long form with many fields. Some of the fields get their data from separate `DIV`, where there are other more specific fields.

Every field, along with its label, is included into a separate block. To highlight the fields there is a CSS `:hover` for their class.

The CSS `:hover`on the fields blocks works smoothly, and also the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` over the many `DIV` passing data to them, using the following Javascript:

```
function LineOn(whichOne) {
    document.getElementById(whichOne).style.backgroundColor = '#cf0';
}

function LineOff(whichOne) {
    document.getElementById(whichOne).style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
}
```

But, after the execution of the Javascript, the `hover` stops to work (i.e. the block remains white), without reporting any console error or message.

This happens both with Firefox 36.0.3 and with Chrome 39.0.2171.71, running on a Slackware current release.

Is there a sort of hierarchy giving to the background color set with Javascript the priority over the one defined in the `<style>` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, styles defined directly in the element's style property overrides any value set in CSS, unless that style has !important on it.

CSS specificity http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector

The priority level of the selector is decided in Point of combination of selectors.

- style attribute = a
- number of ID attributes in the selector = b
- number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector = c
- number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector = d

That's one good reason not to set styles attributes; set a CSS  class instead yet.

Comment: **any** is perhaps a bit overstated. This could be one of the rare cases where the use of `!important` could be justified...

Comment: The `!important` made my night! Now the `:hover` is working again.